# Cannot see full words in the output

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to make this program to print strings but I **cannot see full words in the output** (in console). There will be words in this order: *artictle* (for example: "the", "a", "one", "some", "any"), *noun*, *preposition*, *article*, *noun*.

If I make print that strings without using a function, it works properly. But if I use my function the output is incorrect.

I've been thinking about it for a long time but still I don't understand the reason of such behavior.Could you tell me what's  wrong in this program, please?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int printSentence(int number, const char *article, const char *noun, const char *verb, const char *preposition);

int main(){

    int number;

    const char *article[5] = {"the", "a", "one", "some", "any"};
    const char *noun[5] = {"boy", "girl", "dog", "town", "car"};
    const char *verb[5] = {"drove", "jumped", "ran", "walked", "skipped"};
    const char *preposition[5] = {"to", "from", "over", "on", "under"};

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    /* works properly */
    printf("%s ",  article[0 + rand() % 4] );
    printf("%s ",  noun[0 + rand() % 4] );
    printf("%s ",  verb[0 + rand() % 4] );
    printf("%s ",  preposition[0 + rand() % 4] );
    printf("%s ",  article[0 + rand() % 4] );
    printf("%s\n", noun[0 + rand() % 4] );


    printf("And now I use function:\n")
    printf("Enter the number of sentences to generate (enter 1): \n");
        scanf("%d", &number);
    /* won't work properly */
    printSentence(number, *article, *noun, *verb, *preposition);


    return 0;
}

int printSentence(int num, const char *a, const char *n, const char *v, const char *p){

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < num; i++){

        printf("%s ",  &a[0 + rand() % 4] );
        printf("%s ",  &n[0 + rand() % 4] );
        printf("%s ",  &v[0 + rand() % 4] );
        printf("%s ",  &p[0 + rand() % 4] );
        printf("%s ",  &a[0 + rand() % 4] );
        printf("%s\n", &n[0 + rand() % 4] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**BEFORE:**

[image: **BEFORE:**]

**AFTER SOLVING THE PROBLEM:**

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "the output is incorrect".  Give us some examples!!!  (But the reason it's incorrect is that you're indexing strings, not arrays, so you'll print bytes out of the middle of the array.)

Comment: @HotLicks, I've said "not full strings". The problem was solved. But wait... 

I've update it with pictures so other people will quickly understand this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you call the function with e.g. `*article` you pass only the *first* string in the array. You need to pass the whole arrays:

```
printSentence(number, article, noun, verb, preposition);
```

You then need to change the function declaration of course:

```
int printSentence(int number, const char **article, const char **noun, const char **verb, const char **preposition);
```

And don't use the address-of operator in the function when printing the string.

Answer (score 1):

The `rand() % 4` expression will give 0, 1, 2 or 3, but never 4. You will miss the last ones. If you have 5 elements do `rand() % 5`.

To pass the arrays do not use the `*` as in `*article`, just use them and let them decay into pointers:

```
printSentence(number, article, noun, verb, preposition);
```

The function will have to be declared to get an array-of-pointers or a pointer-to-pointer, they are synonyms here, so choose your favorite:

```
int printSentence(int num, const char **a, const char *n[], const char **v, const char *p[])
```

And to print it, just use the pointer-to-pointer as if it were an array:

```
printf("%s ",  a[0 + rand() % 5] );
```

UPDATE: A litte explanation to understand what you are getting with your code:

- When you pass `*article` to the function, you are actually passing the first element of the array. Note that arrays usually decay into pointers, so `article[0]` is the same as `*(article + 0)` and `*article`. That is simply `"the"`.
- Your function gets the string `"the"`. Let's say the random number is 2, you will print `&a[2]` that is `&*(a + 2)` which is the same as `a + 2` that is the pointer to the third letter of the string and you will get a simple `e` in the console.
- Note that there are a few strings shorter than 3 chars, so you may occasionally get garbage instead, if you happen to overflow the string.

PS: Just out of curiosity, what's the point with all these `0 +`? A placeholder for a future argument?

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy: Well, if you changed the code and it still doesn't work, you should update the question with the new code, or else we will be unable to know what is wrong.

Comment: no, thanks.  The problem was in passing `*article` instead of `**article` to the function.

Comment: @JulianKhlevnoy: That makes no sense. `**article` is just a `const char`!

Comment: I meant that I needed to pass the whole arrays.

Comment: @YulianKhlevnoy: In C you never pass the whole array. You pass the array decayed to pointer to first element. The only way to pass the whole array would be to embed it in a struct. And then, you should pass the struct as pointer anyway...

Answer (score 1):

In

```
int printSentence(int num, const char *a, ...
```

what is `a` *supposed* to be? It's meant to be an array of `const char *`, right? That's what type `article` has, and you want this to be the same.

So, it should look like:

```
int printSentence(int num, const char *a[], ...
```

or

```
int printSentence(int num, const char **a, ...
```